# Google analytics with iOS, data does not send

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

So I've integrated Google Analytics in my app and everything seems to be running smoothly, but the data does not get sent from my app to Google. I've imported all the header files and the frameworks, but the information won't send.

My delegate-file looks like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true
    GAI.sharedInstance().dispatchInterval = 20
    GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("my-secret-id")

    return true
}
```

And then I'm trying to send an event in my viewDidLoad, like this:

```
    let tracker: GAITracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker

    tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("demo_cat", action: "press_button", label: "demo_label", value: nil).build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

but nothing happens. I can't find out what other steps I need to complete for it to work.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to send this code

```
let tracker: GAITracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("demo_cat", action: "press_button", label: "demo_label", value: nil).build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

In viewDidAppear() method, so that event can trigger after view get completely loaded. In viewDidLoad() method could not send event, at the time view is getting ready.

May this help you.

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: Does not work. Also, it doesn't make much sense that the GAITracker should be dependent on the view appearing?

Comment: You can refer this Obj-c Tutorial from very known site, There are some points you can Consider like, 4 lines in App delegate, Send event in each file with in viewdidapear. http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios

Comment: Do you know if I should include the libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a file in my bridging header?